# Unable to send mail with the mail command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email

I am unable to cause the 'mail' command to send mail from my linux ubuntu 15.10 computer. File 'mail.log' typically reports "Connection timed out".

I issue the command: 'mail -s "my subject" recipient@domain.com < filename', where 'filename' is a file containing my message.

Specifically, the log reports:

```
Jan 5 12:29:53 pegasus postfix/smtp[9006]: connect to mx01.gmx.com[74.208.5.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan 5 12:30:23 pegasus postfix/smtp[9006]: connect to mx00.gmx.com[74.208.5.4]:25: Connection timed out
```

I suspect that my ISP (verizon) is blocking port 25 and thus causing the problem: however, I have been unsuccessful in trying to change the smtp port to either 465 (as Verizon recommends) or 587 (as others recommend). Following is my master.cf file:

```
smtp inet n - - - - smtpd

465 inet n - - - - smtpd

#smtp inet n - - - 1 postscreen
#smtpd pass - - - - - smtpd
#dnsblog unix - - - - 0 dnsblog
#tlsproxy unix - - - - 0 tlsproxy
#submission inet n - - - - smtpd
# -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
# -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
# -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
# -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
# -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
# -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
# -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
# -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
# -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
# -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps inet n - - - - smtpd
# -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
# -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
# -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
# -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
# -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
# -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
# -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
# -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
# -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authentica -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628 inet n - - - - qmqpd
pickup unix n - - 60 1 pickup
cleanup unix n - - - 0 cleanup
qmgr unix n - n 300 1 qmgr
#qmgr unix n - n 300 1 oqmgr
tlsmgr unix - - - 1000? 1 tlsmgr
rewrite unix - - - - - trivial-rewrite
bounce unix - - - - 0 bounce
defer unix - - - - 0 bounce
trace unix - - - - 0 bounce
verify unix - - - - 1 verify
flush unix n - - 1000? 0 flush
proxymap unix - - n - - proxymap
proxywrite unix - - n - 1 proxymap
smtp unix - - - - - smtp
relay unix - - - - - smtp
# -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq unix n - - - - showq
error unix - - - - - error
retry unix - - - - - error
discard unix - - - - - discard
local unix - n n - - local
virtual unix - n n - - virtual
lmtp unix - - - - - lmtp
anvil unix - - - - 1 anvil
scache unix - - - - 1 scache
#
uucp unix - n n - - pipe
flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail unix - n n - - pipe
flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp unix - n n - - pipe
flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n n - 2 pipe
flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman unix - n n - - pipe
flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
${nexthop} ${user}
```

Comment: Mail between servers is still transported over port 25, and like you say, is blocked by some ISPs. I personally have my mail server running on a VPS because of this issue :/ You could request that your ISP unblock the port.

Comment: There are also services you can use which would circumvent this. See [this](https://www.noip.com/blog/2013/03/26/my-isp-blocks-smtp-port-25-can-i-still-host-a-mail-server/).

Answer (score 0):

`master.cf` only defines which services & ports your Postfix will *listen on*, i.e. which incoming connections to accept. It does not affect how *outgoing* mail is sent.

Now, while Postfix has [quite a few options](http://www.postfix.org/smtp.8.html) for its "smtp" transport, it doesn't actually let you change the SMTP port. But that's fine, because even if you *did* change the outgoing SMTP port to 587 or whatever, it wouldn't do any good – most receiving servers are not *listening* on that port anyway; your error messages would simply change to "Connection refused" (or perhaps "Message rejected; authentication needed"). **The SMTP mail exchange (server-to-server) port is 25, end of story.**

---

Your "recommendations" probably come from instructions about configuring the mail server to *accept* SMTP connections from a mail app such as Thunderbird or Outlook – indeed the SMTP client-to-server (mail submission) port is 587, and some older configurations still use 465 for this.

At first, port 25 was used for *all* mail, but later it was [separated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4409) into 25 for server-server mail exchange and 587 for client-server mail submission. This allows the server to apply different rules to each – e.g. it's allowed to fix up certain problems in client-submitted mail, and ISPs can block port 25 while still allowing 587.

(Some mail apps used port 465 for "SMTPS" – SMTP with TLS (like HTTPS) – but it had downsides like not being usable for server-server communications. It was eventually replaced by STARTTLS over port 25 & 587. IANA has since reassigned port 465 to another protocol, and it shouldn't be used for mail anymore.)

---

So what to do in your case? There are a few general options.

First, if you're trying to turn your computer into a full mailserver for your own domain:

- Preferred option: Ask your ISP to unblock SMTP connections. (Some ISPs *do* remove the blocks if you ask nicely and promise not to spam.)
- Make Postfix use the ISP-provided "relay" server aka smarthost. (Only some ISPs offer this, though, and you'll still need to do something for *incoming* mail, too...)
- Make all SMTP connections go through a VPN. (Ideally it should be a VPN through *your own* rented server somewhere – don't even think about the privacy-oriented "Hide my ass"-type VPNs, they already block port 25 the same way for all the same reasons.)

Or, if you just want `mail` to send mail from an existing account (e.g. Gmail or GMX):

- Again, configure Postfix to use Gmail's or GMX's "relay" server – essentially make it work like a regular mail app, going through [smtp.gmail.com]:587, with your username & password.

  (There are quite a few "postfix gmail" tutorials out there, but you could also replace Postfix entirely with a relay-only tool like `msmtp` or `esmtp`, which were made for this purpose.)
- Or install *s-nail* (previously known as heirloom-mailx) – a version of `mail` that knows how to use SMTP directly without going through the OS mail system. (That's how other mail apps work, anyway.) The command will still be `mail`.

  (If I remember correctly, GNU mailutils also has a `mail` command with SMTP support.)